# Unicode conversion from C# to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, unicode

I have an issue that´s giving me many problems. I need to set from an cshtml using C# code some variables to javascript. The problem is that accutes and the spanish "ñ" are showed like unicode strings in the window.

I´m trying this code:

```
@:var nombrePersona = '@System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(participante.Nombre))'
@:var apellidoPersona = '@System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(participante.Apellidos))'
```

And the result in javascript is like:

"Jes'&'#250;s" and it should be "Jesús"

Any idea of how to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var nombrePersona = '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(participante.Nombre))'
var apellidoPersona = '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(participante.Apellido))'
```

**EDIT**

Also. If you fill `HtmlDecode()` with a badly formatted string, it won't work. Try cleaning it first:

```
"Jes'&'#250;s".Replace("'", "")  // "Jes&#250;s"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var nombrePersona = '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(participante.Nombre))'
var apellidoPersona = '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(participante.Apellido))'
```

Saludos.